# React TS onCLick type confuses event with my variable

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass in a var into onClick handler, the functionality works but TS is throwing a error which I cant resolve:

TYPE:

```
    export type ButtonType = {
  name: string;
  buttonStyle: string;
  onClick?: (id: number) => void;
};
```

REUSABLE BUTTON:

```
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      className={buttonTypeStyle(buttonStyle)}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {name}
    </button>
  );
};
```

IN URLLIST COMPONENT:

```
const handleOnCLick = (id: number) => {
    return copiedUrlId !== id ? dispatch(setCopiedAction({ id })) : 0;
  };

  return (
    <section className={style.container}>
      <ul className={style.container__urlList}>
        {urls.length > 0 &&
          urls.map((url: any) => {
            return (
              <li key={urls.id} className={style.container__url}>
                <p>original url</p>
                <hr />
                <div className={style.container__urlDivider}>
                  <p>{url.shortenUrl}</p>
                  <Button
                    name={`${copiedUrlId === url.id ? "Copied!" : "Copy"}`}
                    buttonStyle={
                      copiedUrlId === url.id
                        ? "smallSquareCopied"
                        : "smallSquare"
                    }
                    onClick={() => handleOnCLick(url.id)}
                  />
                </div>
              </li>
            );
          })}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
```

ERROR:

```
TS2322: Type '((id: number) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
  Type '(id: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Types of parameters 'id' and 'event' are incompatible.
      Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    16 |       type="submit"
    17 |       className={buttonTypeStyle(buttonStyle)}
  > 18 |       onClick={onClick}
       |       ^^^^^^^
    19 |     >
    20 |       {name}
    21 |     </button>
```

Think that the onCLick passes `event` object by default and TS confuses event with the variable i am passing `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button's onClick attribute expects a function with or without an argument of type `MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`.

Most of the people use it like this (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {}

### Fix for your code:

```
export type ButtonType = {
  name: string;
  buttonStyle: string;
  onClick?: (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => void;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, so i never need to type any of the params in when typing a function?

Comment: You might need it, but at least not when you're gonna use it as element attribute.